# Excel VBA: cannot set range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble troubleshooting a simple border function. The funny thing is, I thought this worked yesterday. But when I opened the workbook today (saved from yesterday), something isn't working.

I can compile the project containing the code below. However, when running, I get the following error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Helpful, no? Well, when I hit "debug" the line where I assign my_range is highlighted. The locals window shows no value is assigned to my_range. Why would this range have trouble taking an assignment like this?

I'm using Excel 2007 on a Win7 box. Here's the full procedure code:

```
Public Sub borders_test()

'activate the sheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'create a range, and assign to it
Dim my_range As Range
my_range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)

'set a red border around the range
With my_range.Borders
  .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  .Weight = xlMedium
End With

'now delete the border
'With my_range.Borders
'  .LineStyle = xlNone
'End With

End Sub
```

Taking the lines out from underneath the my_range assignment makes no difference.

Comment: use `Set my_range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)` instead. When you assign _object_ to variable, you should always use `Set` keyword

Comment: that's got it, if you post as an answer i can mark as answered. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
Dim my_range As Range
Set my_range = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)
```

When you assign *object* to variable, you should always use `Set` keyword.

Btw, this post may help you in future: [how to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select):)